# How to choose bulk aluminum capacitor value and amount for PCB supply input?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pcb-design

Is there a general rule to follow when spec’ing bulk aluminum capacitors for PCB power supply? I have a 24-32 V input that is 1-2 A nominal and 5 A spikes. I was thinking 2 x 220 uF 63 V caps, however that is just an assumption so would like to know actual reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a specification on maximum ripple voltage you can tolerate, and you need to know the minimum peak  output voltage from the rectifier (at minimum mains voltage you choose to accept) and whether it's a half-wave or full-wave rectifier and your mains frequency. Your proposed 440uF capacitance is very much inadequate for most purposes.

Comment: please clarify the title ... `bulk aluminum value` does not really mean anything

Comment: It's just a matter of dividing integrated charge by allowable voltage drop. The integrated charge will be your 5 A times whatever time period of interest. For example, a 5 A draw over a 10 ms period with an acceptable 1/2 volt drop would mean 100 mF.

Comment: Thanks all! Just to be more specific it will be powered by a 28V battery and DCDC. No AC/ mains involved.

Comment: If the supply comes from DCDC switch mode converter, you need to say which converter. It runs at some frequency, it responds to load transients in some way, and it tolerates some amount of capacitance before it goes unstable. Based only on info you give, a safe range cannot be determined.

Comment: So I have no exposure to the DCDC specs. That is outside of my boundary diagram and I am looking for this to work with whatever DCDC they decide to use

Comment: DC-DC converters can be arbitrarily poor. You may want to stipulate typical/example parts in the manual (that you have tested and verified are compatible). What else, what about surge? Presumably the DC-DC will need to tolerate anything like load dump (if applicable)?  Also, is it a 1:1 ratio DC-DC? That doesn't sound very useful, unless it's an isolator--?

Comment: It will be a 800v to 28V DCDC. Just to be clear these caps are not for the DCDC. These are just for a contactor/relay driving PCB that will be powered by a 28V battery which is charged up by the mentioned DCDC. My plan was just to stick a bidirectional TVS on voltage input pin for load dump protection?